# nconf deployment.ini configuration for a basic Nagios server on CentOS 6.2

Tags: centos, deployment, nagios

I have set up nconf and Nagios but I cannot figure out how to configure `deployment.ini` to properly deploy the generated configuration to `/usr/local/nagios/etc`.

Here are the directory listings of interest:

```
[jshin@nag0 tmp]$ ls
Default_collector  global

[jshin@nag0 tmp]$ cd Default_collector/
[jshin@nag0 Default_collector]$ ls
advanced_services.cfg  hostgroups.cfg  service_dependencies.cfg  services.cfg
host_dependencies.cfg  hosts.cfg       servicegroups.cfg

[jshin@nag0 Default_collector]$ cd ..
[jshin@nag0 tmp]$ cd global/
[jshin@nag0 global]$ ls
checkcommands.cfg  contacts.cfg        misccommands.cfg       timeperiods.cfg
contactgroups.cfg  host_templates.cfg  service_templates.cfg

[jshin@nag0 global]$ cd ..
[jshin@nag0 tmp]$ cd /usr/local/nagios/etc/
[jshin@nag0 etc]$ ls
cgi.cfg  htpasswd.users  nagios.cfg  objects  resource.cfg

[jshin@nag0 etc]$ cd objects/
[jshin@nag0 objects]$ ls
commands.cfg  localhost.cfg  switch.cfg     timeperiods.cfg
contacts.cfg  printer.cfg    templates.cfg  windows.cfg
```

Here is my `deployment.ini` (pretty much the default setting)

```
;; LOCAL deployment ;;

[extract config]
type        = local
source_file = "/var/www/html/nconf/output/NagiosConfig.tgz"
target_file = "/tmp/"
action      = extract

[copy collector config]
type        = local
source_file = "/tmp/Default_collector/"
target_file = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/Default_collector/"
action      = copy

[copy global config]
type        = local
source_file = "/tmp/global/"
target_file = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/global"
action      = copy
reload_command = "service nagios restart"
```

What I am wondering is why the directory structure that the default `deployment.ini` seems to suggest, with `Default_collector` and `global`, is different from the one that Nagios has by default, with only a folder called `objects`. What am I missing?

Or more importantly, how does your `deployment.ini` look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I cannot figure out how to configure `deployment.ini` to properly
>   deploy the generated configuration to `/usr/local/nagios/etc`.

After generating Nagios config, it simply uses some commands such as: `gunzip`, `tar`, `scp`, `rsync`, ... to copy to the Nagios config directory.

With the above config, go to the Web UI, hit the **Generate Nagios config** link and followed by click on the **Deploy** button, it will tell you which step has failed. Click the plus signs (+) to see the details info:

```
copy global config  FAILED

PHP mkdir:  OK  
Create target directory (/usr/local/nagios/etc/global)
PHP copy:   OK  
recursive copy(/tmp/global/, /usr/local/nagios/etc/global)
system call     FAILED  
service nagios restart
sh: service: command not found
```

As you can see from the above error, you missed the trailing slash in [`target_file`](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=nconf:help:documentation:modules:deployment:types:local). Moreover, you need to make sure that `apache` can [reload Nagios](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=nconf:help:documentation:modules:deployment:main#restarting_nagios) without prompting password.

Edit the [copy global config] as belows:

```
[copy global config]
type        = local
source_file = "/tmp/global/"
target_file = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/global/"
action      = copy
reload_command = "sudo /etc/init.d/nagios reload"
```

*(you can use `/sbin/service` if you want)*

it will work as you expected.

But, wait... why not extract the files direct to `/usr/local/nagios/etc/`:

```
[extract config]
type        = local
source_file = "/var/www/html/nconf/output/NagiosConfig.tgz"
target_file = "/usr/local/nagios/etc/"
action      = extract
reload_command = "sudo /etc/init.d/nagios reload"
```

> What I am wondering is why the directory structure that the default
>   `deployment.ini` seems to suggest, with `Default_collector` and
>   `global`, is different from the one that Nagios has by default, with
>   only a folder called `objects`. What am I missing?

No matter. You can put the config files in the any folder which you want but don't forget to tell Nagios in the main config file [nagios.cfg](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=nconf:help:documentation:start:start_guide#nagioscfg).